# Cut paragraph (circumstantially) in Xcode 5 with a key binding?

Tags: xcode

When I press Command+X in Xcode 5, I want the key binding to act differently based on two circumstances.

1. If there is a selection made, copy the selection, then delete it. This behavior already exists in Xcode.
2. If there is **NO** selection made, copy the current line (a.k.a. the paragraph), then delete it.

Is a conditional key binding like that possible to do in Xcode?

I've read through [**this article**](http://www.funky-monkey.nl/blog/2014/02/adding-keybindings-in-xcode-5/) on adding key bindings to Xcode 5. The only problem I'm having is the conditional aspect of such a key binding. Thanks for any help.